# what does the comma mean in g = filter(lambda x: x in a, b)

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I'm not sure what the comma means in the following syntax:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,3,5,6,7,8]
g = filter(lambda x: x in a, b)
```

Would that be equivalent to:

```
if x in a and x in b
```

because that's what happens.  Also, is this comma only legit in lambda functions?

Comment: If you understand list comprehensions, it's equivalent to `g = [x for x in b if x in a]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`b` is the collection to perform the filter on.

`filter` takes two arguments. The first one is a function(which can be a lambda) and the second one is the collection to apply the function to. The function gets applied to each item in the collection.

So in this case we have:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,3,5,6,7,8]
```

and

```
g = filter(lambda x: x in a, b)
```

the `,` separates the arguments. The first argument is the lambda function, so just `lambda x: x in a`, so it filters the collection by only returning a collection of items that return `True`. So for our first item we have the first item in `b`, which is 2. 2 is in `a`, so it will return `True` and it will be in the result of the `filter` function, `g`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  Nice to see you again.  In case you forgot I was the one who was trying to insert an item into a dictionary in a specific spot.

Comment: Oh! Glad to help again! I thought your name looked familiar.